# Python import issues

Tags: python

I have never used Python before and am trying learn it on the fly. I have this file. I installed python 2.7 have added it the path. when I try python [filename].py I get errors saying

import requests,sys,csv,os,re,urllib2,urllib,time,traceback,string
ImportError: No module named requests.

Am I missing something here. Where would I find these and how do I get this running

Comment: Yes, you are missig the `requests` module, apparently... It's a popular one, but it isn't part of the standard library.

Comment: I'd suggest spending a bit of time learning about python modules, where to find them, and how to install them. This is fairly basic stuff with many getting-started tutorials available.

Comment: Please consider using Python 3.6+

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `requests` package:

```
pip install requests
```

Tutorial about installing packages [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)